# ROLLBACK TRANSACTION used as an undo

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a stored proc that performs some work based on a few parameters.  This is destructive work and one of the parameters is ReallyDoIt (Y/N)

What I'd like to do is create the proc like so

```
create proc DoSomething @ParamOne int, @ReallyDoIT char(1)
as
begin
 begin try
  begin transaction
  do stuff
  get logging info
  do some more stuff
  add to the logging info
  etc....
  if @ReallyDoIt = 'Y' COMMIT Transaction
  else ROLLBACK TRAN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 IF @@trancount >0 ROLLBACK TRAN
end catch
```

I'm looking specifically to see if this is an appropriate design for a stored procedure.  Is there anything that I'm missing or can hose up if I do it this way.

Are there situations where using this method will fail or produce unwanted results in the data.  Should I instead use a separate block of code to implement the logging only if @ReallyDoIt is 'N'

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: It will work.  I've used it before.  I'm wondering if I'm playing with fire though.

Comment: What is your intention, what do you hope to accomplish with this parameter? If it is `N` you're doing a bunch of stuff that's never going to be part of your database. Is this for testing or something like that?

Comment: @DaytonBrown - I'm not sure why you are asking us if you are playing with fire.  You know you are when you execute this stored procedure by passing the parameter 'Y'.  You need to figure out whether what you are doing is safe or not.

Comment: @TT.  Yes :-)  Both testing, and making sure you really want to make the changes.  In the changed record counts should in all cases be pretty small.

Comment: I'm assuming that the parameter in question is used to do a dry-run of the procedure, to see if it will crash or return the right data without actually changing the data in the database. I ask because the most obvious way to implement the parameter functionality as it is named is that you simply don't call the method at all.

Comment: @TT. - It doesnt have to be N, could be any character but Y.

Comment: This will be a manual data fix procedure.  There will be times when you aren't completely sure the values are correct.  The logging will help to enhance your confidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this design in the past in order to be able to unit test stored procedures. This approach allows to verify row counts without actually altering the data. However, I would recommend you default `@ReallyDoIt` to `Y` so the stored procedure always works correctly once deployed. You should also make sure you do not do too much work inside the transaction as it will result in an heavy load on the transaction log and will lock the tables that are being updated.